# Configure NHibernate 3.3.1 for Castle Windsor after 3.0 upgrade

Tags: nhibernate, castle-windsor

In an existing project I just upgraded NHibernate from 3.0 to 3.3. The upgrade was not as straightforward as I thought, but is required by a former incompatibility with MySQL connector I found on SO too.

The problem is that I can't use `NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory` anymore because it requires NH 3.0 (I got a `FileLoadException` for `NHibernate, Version=3.0.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4`).

Looking well inside NH 3.3 zip, I saw there is no BytecodeProvider. In NH 3.0 there was a "RequiredForLazyLoading" directory where I took everything I needed.

So, what should I do in NH 3.3.1 to enable lazy loading? I was comfortable with Castle, that I just upgraded to latest version 3.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

External bytecode providers are no longer required. NHibernate now has an internal one.

Just remove the references to it.

Comment: So will NH detect Castle Windsor automatically and use it?

Comment: NH itself doesn't use Castle at all.