# NHibernate.Bytecode.Unity - create proxy instance failed exception without Not.LazyLoad()

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, unity-container

I have .NET project with NHibernate and NHibernate.Bytecode.Unity as proxy factory, also i use Unity as DI container. I've faced with next problem - when i try to call .ToList() method on query, i have  this exception:

```
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "CRM.Data.Entity.DealTaskStage", name = "CRM.Data.Entity.DealTaskStage".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: ArgumentNullException - Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: arguments
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving CRM.Data.Entity.DealTaskStage,CRM.Data.Entity.DealTaskStage
```

I have next configuration of relationship (using FluentNHibernate):

```
References<DealTaskStage>(x => x.Stage).ForeignKey("stage_id");
```

If i append Not.LazyLoad() to this config, error does not appear, but i want to find better solution. So, can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: make sure you have `DealTaskStage` registered in your container

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - latest NHibernate does not need any proxy provider.

[Configure NHibernate 3.3.1 for Castle Windsor after 3.0 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329798/configure-nhibernate-3-3-1-for-castle-windsor-after-3-0-upgrade)